# Visual Studio - Run Automated TestMethods with a specific TestCategory value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, azure-pipelines, runsettings

In Visual Studio web app, I'm adding a task after the deployment has successfully built the environment to run smoke tests.  The smoke tests have a TestCategory of 'SmokeTest'.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the task only run TestMethods that have the TestCategory of "SmokeTest".  I've read that what I need to do is put something in the 'Override test run parameters' field, but I'm not sure exactly what.

Additional Information:
-Using Visual Studio 2017 Community
-Using Selenium framework w/ C#

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to find the test filter criteria field and enter the following.

**TestCategory=SmokeTest**

[image]

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/09/04/supplying-run-time-parameters-to-tests/